# How to use values in matrix visualization for further calculation?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

[The desired result along with sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRMbL.png)

Hi, as can be seen in the image I am trying to see how I can use the values in a matrix visualization for further calculation.

I did find one way but it is very tedious as in the fact that measures can only take 1 scalar value so I will have to create one for each value in the ww column, let me know if you need further clarification

as stated earlier I tried to create a measure and then assign it a DAX code using variable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JixvO.png)